# How can I only get a numerical answer when applying a function to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pubchem

This is the code I have until now:

```
import pandas as pd
import pubchempy
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("Data.tsv.txt", sep="\t")

from pubchempy import get_properties

df['CID'] = df['CID'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('.0',''))
df['CID'] = df['CID'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('0',''))

df = df.drop(df[df.CID=='nan'].index)

df = df.drop( df.index.to_list()[150:] ,axis = 0 )


df['CID']= df['CID'].map(lambda x: get_properties(identifier=x, properties='MolecularWeight') if float(x) > 0 else pd.NA)

print(df)
```

The output that I'm getting under the 'CID' column is this:

CID

[{'CID': 5339, 'MolecularWeight': '398.4'}]

What can I do so that I only get the numerical 'MolecularWeight' value in the 'CID' column (eg. 398.4 in column one etc)?

Comment: Can you add output of `print(df)`

Comment: ```df['CID']= df['CID'].map(lambda x: float(get_properties(identifier=x, properties='MolecularWeight')['MolecularWeight']) if float(x) > 0 else pd.NA)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. You don't need to `lambda` to `replace`, and you can cascade them like `str.replace('.0','').replace(('0','')`. BTW, if there is any zero anywhere in your CID it will just remove it. Also, you are comparing to `"nan"` when it is much easier&faster to compare it to `nan`. **Is [{'CID': 5339, 'MolecularWeight': '398.4'}] one of the entries of `df["CID"]` after read_csv?**

Comment: No [{'CID': 5339, 'MolecularWeight': '398.4'}] is one of the entries after df['CID']= df['CID'].map(lambda x: get_properties(identifier=x, properties='MolecularWeight') if float(x) > 0 else pd.NA). I used lambda because in order to use str.replace('.0','').replace(('0','') I would have to provide a known string value. What my code does is that it uses the pubchempy.get_properties to search through pubchem and return the molecular weight of a compound given a specific identification value  (the values in the 'CID' column).

Comment: `df['CID'] = df['CID'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('.0',''))` + 
`df['CID'] = df['CID'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('0',''))`
is actually the same as doing `df['CID'] = df['CID'].astype(str).str.replace('(.)?0',"")`. BTW, if you don't @ us, we don't see that you replied

Comment: @ZaeroDivide Oh damn lol, didn't even know you could @ someone, thank you. Wait so are you saying I could combing the pubchempy.get_properties function with the df['CID'] = df['CID'].astype(str).str.replace('(.)?0',"") function?

Comment: @mujjiga
 I tried to add an image of the output but my reputation isn't high enough unfortunately... But the column output is the same as what I posted. The code you worked also didn't work, the error says, "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". –

Comment: @New_to_cofing Give full dataframe or at least a part of it. Use df_to_dict and copy/paste here, like this we can reproduce the error in our IDE.